# Content management without using a cms, what is the best practice?

Tags: content-management-system

I'm just about to start a website and I've decided to stay away from WordPress and other CMSs - I just want to build a site myself.

The site is mostly static, except there will be the odd news item added to it. So say I want to display the last 5 news items on the front page and then have a link to show all the news items. How do I go about this?

I learnt to do this with XML an Uni in the past, but it seems that is out of fashion. Is there a replacement or should I be storing these news items in a SQL database where I can just sort them by date and pull out the last 5?

I really don't want a CMS! Just a push in the right direction.

Comment: *rolls eyes* This is why there are so many CMS's out there, for people who don't really have a clue how to build a website for their exact purpose.

Comment: Not a real question/Not constructive/Off topic. Please consult the FAQ. I would choose a [different] *existing* tool ... unless your *goal* is to create a *new* tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any clearly "right" solution, but I use PHP to generate pages with a MySQL backend. This seems to be one of the simpler approaches possible for mostly-static content. You can fairly quickly learn enough to get the job done, and deploying and modifying the website is trivial (edit the source file and hit refresh on your browser).

Comment: What worked for me was to find source code for a site similar to what I was trying to do and then modify that to fit my own needs. So, I started from someone's really basic Wiki implementation and turned it into a site to post notes, homework, and grades for my high school classes.

Comment: Thanks, what I need is really simple so I'm starting with the simple stuff. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: You may want to avoid AJAX at first - it adds a whole other level of complexity. This tutorial looks promising: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: I'm ok with ajax, but maybe I will avoid it to start off with, thanks again